# structuremap object reference with particular dependency

Tags: structuremap4

I am new to structuremap. 
I want to get Shopper classes object with either "master" or "visa" dependency based on user input. 
In below code I have created two concrete classes MasterCard and Visa from ICreditCard. I am injecting dependency of ICreditCard but when code is executing based on user's option I want to inject MasterCard or Visa depdency to Shopper class and get reference of that Shopper class object.

Can someone tell me how to do it if it is possible. I also want to know if I want to initialise object in some other class then how to do it(is it by exposing a method returning container object?)

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var container = new Container();
        container.Configure(c => c.For<ICreditCard>().Use<MasterCard>().Named("master"));
        container.Configure(x => x.For<ICreditCard>().Use<Visa>().Named("visa"));

        //how to get instance of Shopper with master card object reference?
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public class Visa : ICreditCard
    {
        public string Charge()
        {
            return "Visa... Visa";
        }

        public int ChargeCount
        {
            get { return 0; }
        }
    }

    public class MasterCard : ICreditCard
    {
        public string Charge()
        {
            ChargeCount++;
            return "Charging with the MasterCard!";
        }

        public int ChargeCount { get; set; }
    }

    public interface ICreditCard
    {
        string Charge();
        int ChargeCount { get; }
    }

    public class Shopper
    {
        private readonly ICreditCard creditCard;

        public Shopper(ICreditCard creditCard)
        {
            this.creditCard = creditCard;
        }

        public int ChargesForCurrentCard
        {
            get { return creditCard.ChargeCount; }
        }

        public void Charge()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(creditCard.Charge());
        }
    }
}
```